# Change ActiveMQ Resource Adapter Defaults Wildfly10

Tags: java, wildfly-10, resource-adapter

I am working with the ActiveMQ Resource Adapter, hooking it into Wildfly 10. I am trying to configure it properly, but I do not know how to change the default property value for ServerURL.

The link here: 
http://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter-properties.html,

states that it defaults to localhost, but I want to default to a different value. Is this possible? I've looked through as much documentation as I can find but it seems this issue is never addressed.

Further, is it possible to change this property to have no default and to be required? Ideally, Wildfly would fail to start if this value is not provided, but right now it is forcing me to attempt to connect to localhost, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially solved using the System Property org.apache.activemq.BROKER_BIND_URL

This Property allows one to set the default URL within the ActiveMQ Connection Factory, however, there still is no way to fail the start up if the System Property is not present. In that case, it still uses localhost for the host.

Thank you to @Varsha for the lead into System Properties, but those were not the correct Property Keys.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start ActiveMQ, it starts on all IP/hostname associated to machine. Hence you can use IP or hostname of ActiveMQ as ServerURL `tcp://IP:61616` in resource adapter configuration.

Default value defined in AMQ_HOME/etc/system.properties

```
# Activemq configuration

activemq.port = 61616
activemq.host = localhost
activemq.url = tcp://${activemq.host}:${activemq.port}
```